# Hide toolbar (inside a AppBarLayout) in a specific fragment

Tags: android, xml, android-fragments, toolbar, appbar

I newly started learning android. For the sake of developing a compatible version with Android Lollipop (API 21) and also android pre-lollipop devices (API15), I define two different styles. The first style supports ActionBar and the other one extends the property `.NoActionBar` which is needed for API21 and above. I think that I may misunderstood the appbar with toolbar and actionbar.

Additionaly, I use two fragments in my main activity. I wonder if there is a way that toolbar (which is inside the AppBarLayout in xml file) be hidden in specific fragment and shown in the other fragment.

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example">
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        ...
        ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```

**app_bar_main.xml**

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">
            <com.example.MyTextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="22sp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/app_name"/>
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

**styles.xml**

```
<resources>
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>
    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

</resources>
```

**styles.xml** (v21)

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The first style supports ActionBar and the other one extends the property .NoActionBar which is needed for API21 and above.

ActionBar is no longer recommended, so you can use [Toolbar](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/Toolbar.html) everywhere. Make your activity extend [AppCompatActivity](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatActivity.html) and set your toolbar as Actionbar using [setSupportActionBar (Toolbar toolbar)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatActivity.html#setSupportActionBar(android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar))

Comment: @inverted_index make your activity extend AppCompatActivity which is included in the support lib, then you can use Toolbar everywhere

Comment: Do you mean that I can remove the `ActionBar` from the styles.xml at all?

Comment: you don't need to edit the current style, you can use AppTheme.NoActionBar theme through out the app

Comment: The code you have posted is generated by android studio right? you don't have to do anything. Android studio will do it for you. just set AppTheme.NoActionBar as your Activity theme in your Manifest file.  cheers :)